# Notification small icon on status bar creating for every notificaton

Tags: android, notifications, icons, statusbar

I'm creating a notification by

```
mNotifyBuilder.setContentTitle(envelope.getSubjectWithDefault(context.getString(R.string.no_subject)))
                .setTicker(sybject)
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setContentInfo(name)
                .setDeleteIntent(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int) id, deleteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT))
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setNumber(count)
                .setGroup(group)
                .addAction(reply)
                .addAction(cancel, context.getString(R.string.delete), dismiss)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(text))
                .setContentText(text);
String noti = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(noti);
        mNotificationManager.notify((int) id, notify);
```

but some phones create for every push their own small icon on the status bar.
How can I found or what I can change in code to fix such notification to work?

Comment: mNotificationManager.notify(1, notify);  Can you try this?

Comment: it shows only the last notification.